# Creating relations in derby sample database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, derby

I am playing with derby sample database in Netbeans. I want to create tables with one to many relation.

I have `courses` and `student`. Course should have all students that take this course in its table and student should have course that he is taking in its table. So far i created

```
CREATE TABLE Course
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Student
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
faculty VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT student_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT student_fk  FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course
);
```

However when i map this using `Hibernate` , the student object does not have course property as whole object , but only its id as integer.

Also how could I create many to one relation for course table?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship mappings should look like this:

```
@Entity
class Course{

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
   private Set<Student> students;

}

@Entity
class Student

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
   private Course course;

}
```

Comment: so i should just execute said sql , create reverse hibernate file , generate mapping file and add this to the POJO classes?

Comment: when you use annotations you dont need hbm mapping files.. you just have to specify packagesToScan hibernate property.

Comment: unless you cannot use annotation.. is that the case? Also are you expecting here from hibernate to create the database on startup? using the hbm2.ddl setting?

Comment: im creating database with derby in netbeans i was hibernate to map tables and manipulate with it.

Comment: Ok great.. so you still have any problems with retrieving your data?

Comment: Hmm , so when i generate entity classes from database using netbeans i can map them with hibernate? This caused error in my case.

Comment: Not sure how you generated them. But, personally i always create the mapping classes manually by myself.